# How to identify which node is serving each customer?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming

I have a linear programming problem. There are two questions:

Consider 2 centers (1,2) that should serve clients [s,b,c,t], What it the minimum distance cost. The formulation is straight forward.
The LP problem is solved and then the indicated red and blue paths will be found (let's assume it is optimal). Solution A or B might be found.
$$\begin{alignat}{2} 
\min_{flow_{ij}} & \sum_{ij \in \Omega} D_{ij}flow_{ij} \\
& Source_i - Sink_i = \sum_{ij \in \Omega} flow_{ij}-flow_{ji} \\
& 0 \leq flow_{i,j} \leq f_{max} \\
& 0\leq Source_i \leq S_{max} \\
& Sink_i \textrm{ is a binary parameter , 1 for all non-source} \\
& \Omega \ \textrm{is the set of arcs} \\ 
\end{alignat}$$
**The second question is how to know which center is serving who by just looking at the network flow variables?**

The ideal answer should be like:

- 1 ---> [b,s]
- 2 ---> [t,c]

ّI need to find the connected components (hopefully without solving extra optimization )

[image]

Comment: How are your variables defined? Are they units of flow (with known demands at each customer), binary variables (either there is or is not flow on this arc) or what? Is the formulation a multicommodity flow network (separate variables on each arc for flows originating at 1 and flows originating at 2) or just a single aggregate variable for each arc?

Comment: How do your network flow variables currently look like?

Comment: @prubin Edited the question.

Comment: Can't you just start with the centers and iterate over all non-zero $flow_{ij}$ variables to trace back if they are connected? Lets consider solution 1: You start with center $1$, see it is connected to $s$, stop as $s$ is not connected to any other node. Same goes for node $b$. Go to center $2$ since there are no connections from center $1$ to any other node. Here you see that it's connected to $t$, now you check if there is a connection from $t$ to another node and indeed there is connection to $c$. Since there are no flow variables left, you stop the algorithm.

Comment: @PeterD basically look for $flow_{i,j} \gt 0$.

Comment: @Sutanu Indeed. I see Rob posted an answer while I was still typing, which explains the approach well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you mentioned, you want to find the connected components of the support graph of the flow variables.  Explicitly, let $$S=\{(i,j)\in\Omega: \text{flow}_{ij}>0 \lor \text{flow}_{ji}>0\},$$
initialize each node to be in its own component, and loop over $S$ once, where in each iteration $(i,j)$ of the loop you merge the two components for node $i$ and node $j$. At the end, the nodes served by a center are the ones that appear in the same component as that center.